# Inconsistent width reported when window is not focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've an Angular Directive that is building a graph. Before building it, I'm looking at the width of the element using `element.width()` and the width reported is not always correct. Basically if my Chrome Tab is not active I will get something way larger and when it's active I get the correct size for the element. No matter if I time it out of 10 seconds to be sure that the DOM is stable.

I'm not able to reproduce the bug within a snippet because it always works.

- Size of the window stays always the same I checked with `$(window).width()`
- Doesn't matter if my elements are floated or absoluted, the bug remains the same
- My divs are responsive, so their width are always in % with some media queries on top of it.

My hack (disgusting one):
`$(window).focus(function () { // recompute the size });` and that works but I hate it.

Some more hints:

- The guilty folk that changes is size alone when focus is a div with a style: `width: 42.5%; float: left;`
- This div is just avec one other with the following style: `width: 22.5%;float: left;`
- I don't have the bug with Firefox
- In Chrome I get the bug only if the tab is not focused, not if the whole browser is not focused

Comment: Seeing the poor level of answers, I will try again to make a reusable case but I can not succeed it. Will build a simple Angular App with my directive and see where it leads to come back with something "more" debuggable.